# C++ condition variable and wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, condition-variable

I am trying to figure out what this code line does. Will it suspend or wait or run the code while count is less than 6?

```
unique_lock<mutex> lck(mtx);
 cv.wait(lck, [this]() { return count <6; });
```

Answer (score 0):

It will wait **until** the `cv` is notified that `count < 6`. From a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait):

> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> while (!pred()) {
>     wait(lock);
> }
> ```
>
> This overload may be used to ignore spurious awakenings while waiting for a specific condition to become true. Note that before enter to this method lock must be acquired, after `wait(lock)` exits it is also reacquired, i.e. lock can be used as a guard to `pred()` access.

You can think of the predicate as the termination condition to stop waiting.

Comment: that is what i thought I add count++ to right blow cv.wait but it does not work out. I am trying to let each thread to print only 5 chars. any idea?

Comment: @RamonLarodo `wait()` blocks. It'll never get to your `count++`. You'd have to increment it in a different thread.

Comment: can you please give me an example code of count++ controlling thread?

Comment: @RamonLarodo There are numerous examples in the reference I posted.

Comment: Thanks Barry, But i dont get the logic. Ok i create another thread to check count but how i can make sure this controller thread will check count after each thread runs? I mean before thread 1 releases its lock maybe thread 1 will print 10 chars not 5? so controller thread cannot interrupt when count hits 5 because thread 1 has the lock? I am right?

Comment: @RamonLarodo I have no idea what any of that meant, but [read the manual](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)